# Getting the Users location with parse

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, geolocation, cllocationmanager

I am trying to make my code that on app loading it updates my parse database with the users current time and location. Here is my current code:

---

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
   PFObject *testObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"TestObject"];
   testObject[@"foo"] = @"bar";
//    PFGeoPoint *point = [PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:40.0 longitude:-30.0];
//    testObject[@"location"] = point;
    [PFGeoPoint geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground:^(PFGeoPoint *geoPoint, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            testObject[@"location"] = geoPoint;
        }
    }];

    [testObject saveInBackground];
```

---

My database updates correctly when I give it a preset lat and long to use but it doesnt work when I use parses code to fetch the users geoPoint. Is this because I am doing this wrong or is it because it will not work when im using the iPhone simulator on my computer. Thanks.

Comment: you saved `testObject` before getting location, write it in completion block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example code is given in the parse [blog](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/fetching-the-users-current-location/) :

```
[PFGeoPoint geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground:^(PFGeoPoint *geoPoint, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"User is currently at %f, %f", geoPoint.latitude, geoPoint.longitude);

        [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:geoPoint forKey:@"currentLocation"];
        [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
    }
}];
```

As per my opinion. You have to save the location from the completion block. you have done it from the outside of the block.

Also you can take a look of iOS Guide for [Geo Location](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#geo)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried to save the location from inside the completion block but the data never makes it to parse.